# autosave keeps saving as "true" or "false" for filename

Tags: excel, vba, save, filenames

something is wrong with the macro, it keeps saving the way i want it to, but names the file "true" or "false". Note: the cell value itself is "=today()"

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename = Range("C6").Value

    FileFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

        CreateBackup = False


ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF

    Filename = Range("c6").Value

        FileFormat = pdf

            Quality = xlQualityStandard

                IncludeDocProperties = True

                    IgnorePrintAreas = False

                        OpenAfterPublish = False

 End Sub
```

Comment: try `Filename:=Range("c6").Text` to get the date as it appears in the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Filename:=Range("c6").Text` to get the date as it appears in the cell.

The operator syntax is `:=` between argument name and argument value.

```
Sub Macro1()
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
      Filename:=Range("C6").Text, _
      FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, _
      CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
      Type:=xlTypePDF, _
      Filename:=Range("c6").Text, _
      FileFormat:=xlpdf, _
      Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
      IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
      IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
      OpenAfterPublish:=False
End Sub
```